# Erdas 2014 process time signature editor supervised classification

Tags: classification, erdas-imagine, point-of-interest

I am currently using erdas imagine 2014 with 64bit OS. Basic configurations of my computer are; i7 3820 3.60 GHz CPU, 16 GB memory (RAM), gforce GTX 680 SLI 256 bit Graphic card ( 2GPU ), 250 GB ssd. It takes 3.50 minutes to complete a process called signature selection from aoi with 1.2 gb layerstack images and less than 500 points.

I wonder if this speed is normal for such a application for a computer like this one, or this is a long time for the computer to finish.

It takes 7.30 minutes on a notebook with i3 processor and 6 gb ram with onboard graphic card.